# Autohotkey: Change Ultrawide 21:9 aspect ratio to 16:9

Tags: autohotkey, aspect-ratio

I have a 38 inch, ultrawide monitor. I have a working AHK script that swaps between a 3840x1600 and 1920x1080 resolution but it doesn't change to a 16:9 aspect ratio, which should leave black bars at the sides of the monitor (when the 21:9 ratio is kept, everything is scaled horizontally out of proportion)

When you change the resolution from 3840 to 1920 in Windows display settings, it will also change the ratio to 16:9, which is what I need.

Here is my working script for the resolution: Please tell me what needs to be changed\added to also change the ratio to 16:9.

```php
x := A_ScreenWidth
;# y := A_ScreenHeight
;# MsgBox, Your screen resolution is : %x%x%y%


if (x = 1920)
{
ChangeResolution(3840, 1600)
Sleep, 500
Run, J:\PRESETS\AUTOHOTKEY SCRIPTS\PRODUCTIVITY\ResizeDefaultWindows.ahk
}
else
ChangeResolution(1920, 1080)
Return

ChangeResolution(Screen_Width := 1920, Screen_Height := 1080, Color_Depth := 32)
{
    VarSetCapacity(Device_Mode,156,0)
    NumPut(156,Device_Mode,36) 
    DllCall( "EnumDisplaySettingsA", UInt,0, UInt,-1, UInt,&Device_Mode )
    NumPut(0x5c0000,Device_Mode,40) 
    NumPut(Color_Depth,Device_Mode,104)
    NumPut(Screen_Width,Device_Mode,108)
    NumPut(Screen_Height,Device_Mode,112)
    Return DllCall( "ChangeDisplaySettingsA", UInt,&Device_Mode, UInt,0 )
}
ExitApp
Return
```

Comment: Would you be fine with a really hacky and somewhat slow (around 5 seconds) solution that opens up the user interface for Display Settings and would use a combination of {Tab} {Spacebar} and the arrow keys to switch between the settings?

Comment: If there is no other way, then that was my plan. I would use the macro recorder to record those steps. I use it for many other things.

Comment: That honestly might be the way to go if no one contributes a proper dllCall solution for it. If you know how to use it, a Macro Recorder would definitely be better than anything I could provide since it can be fine-tuned to work on your specific system and hardware (and I don't have a 38 inch ultrawide monitor that I could test it with lol).

Comment: Strangely enough, the macro recorder will not record once it gets to the Resolution Dropdown. Even the script (Send, {Enter}) will not execute on the Resolution Dropbox. So yes, I'd appreciate your version.

Comment: For @all: [This and other answers on this SU question](https://superuser.com/a/89360/910769) show alternative ways on how to change the display resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `dmDisplayFixedOutput` to `DMDFO_CENTER`<sup>[(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea)</sup> might do the trick.
But you might also get black bars on all four sides.
It might also not make any difference. I had really inconsistent results on different displays when trying this. Your monitor settings will surely also play a part here.
But anyway, worth a try I guess.

---

Lets start off by looking at the `_devicemodeA`<sup>[(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-devmodea)</sup> structure.
I added in the sizes of each member (in bytes) and their offsets:

```
typedef struct _devicemodeA {                   //  size    |   offset
    BYTE   dmDeviceName[CCHDEVICENAME];         //  32          0
    WORD dmSpecVersion;                         //  2           32
    WORD dmDriverVersion;                       //  2           34
    WORD dmSize;                                //  2           36
    WORD dmDriverExtra;                         //  2           38
    DWORD dmFields;                             //  4           40
    union {
      /* printer only fields */
      struct {
        short dmOrientation;                    //  2           44
        short dmPaperSize;                      //  2           46
        short dmPaperLength;                    //  2           48
        short dmPaperWidth;                     //  2           50
        short dmScale;                          //  2           52
        short dmCopies;                         //  2           54
        short dmDefaultSource;                  //  2           56
        short dmPrintQuality;                   //  2           58
      } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
      /* display only fields */
      struct {
        POINTL dmPosition;                      //  8           44
        DWORD  dmDisplayOrientation;            //  4           52
        DWORD  dmDisplayFixedOutput;            //  4           56
      } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME2;
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME;
    short dmColor;                              //  2           60
    short dmDuplex;                             //  2           62
    short dmYResolution;                        //  2           64
    short dmTTOption;                           //  2           66
    short dmCollate;                            //  2           68
    BYTE   dmFormName[CCHFORMNAME];             //  32          70
    WORD   dmLogPixels;                         //  2           102
    DWORD  dmBitsPerPel;                        //  4           104
    DWORD  dmPelsWidth;                         //  4           108
    DWORD  dmPelsHeight;                        //  4           112
    union {
        DWORD  dmDisplayFlags;                  //  4           116
        DWORD  dmNup;                           //  4           116
    } DUMMYUNIONNAME2;
    DWORD  dmDisplayFrequency;                  //  4           120
#if(WINVER >= 0x0400)
    DWORD  dmICMMethod;                         //  4           124
    DWORD  dmICMIntent;                         //  4           128
    DWORD  dmMediaType;                         //  4           132
    DWORD  dmDitherType;                        //  4           136
    DWORD  dmReserved1;                         //  4           140
    DWORD  dmReserved2;                         //  4           144
#if (WINVER >= 0x0500) || (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_NT4)
    DWORD  dmPanningWidth;                      //  4           148
    DWORD  dmPanningHeight;                     //  4           152
#endif                                          //-----
#endif /* WINVER >= 0x0400 */                   //  156 (total)
} DEVMODEA, *PDEVMODEA, *NPDEVMODEA, *LPDEVMODEA;
```

We're interested in the `dmSize`, `dmFields`, `dmDisplayFixedOutput`, `dmPelsWidth` and `dmPelsHeight` members.
On other implementations e.g the `dmDeviceName`, `dmPosition`, `dmDisplayOrientation` and `dmDisplayFrequency` members could be very interesting as well.

---

So we start off by creating a DEVMODE structure and filling it with the our display device's current information. This way we we can only change what we want, as opposed to setting every single required piece of information in there.

So we create a variable `_DEVMODE` and reserve 156 bytes for it.
156 comes from the size we calculated for it above.
The reserving thing is just a thing you have to do for AHK DllCalling, nothing more special to it.

```
VarSetCapacity(_DEVMODE, 156)
```

Then we can use the `EnumDisplaySettingsA`<sup>[(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaysettingsa)</sup> function to fill the structure.
But first we notice the documentation state:

> Before calling **EnumDisplaySettings**, set the **dmSize** member to `sizeof(DEVMODE)`

So lets do that, we know the size to be 156 bytes and we know the offset of the `dmSize` member to be 36 bytes.
`NumPut()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/NumPut.htm)</sup> is used to manipulate memory at a certain memory address:

```
NumPut(156, _DEVMODE, 36)
```

Then we're ready to call `EnumDisplaySettingsA`:

```
DllCall("EnumDisplaySettingsA", Ptr, 0, UInt, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS := -1, UInt, &_DEVMODE)
```

Parameters:

- `lpszDeviceName`: Ptr `0` passed in to indicate NULL<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/DllCall.htm#ptr)</sup>, which means use the current display device. A fancier solution could choose here which monitor to use.
- `iModeNum`: UInt `ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS` (its value is -1) passed in to indicate using the currently used settings, as opposed to settings stored in the registry.
- `*lpDevMode`: UInt `&_DEVMODE` passed in, which means the pointer of our `_DEVMODE` structure.
  `&`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#amp)</sup> is used to get the pointer.

And now the structure should be successfully filled.
Probably good to test it out, so lets try to get the refresh rate with `NumGet()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/NumGet.htm)</sup> as a test:

```
MsgBox, % NumGet(_DEVMODE, 120) " Hz"
```

---

Now we can get onto changing the resolution and setting the `DMDFO_CENTER` flag to hopefully get the desired black bars.

First we set the flags to the `dmFields` members to indicate we are using some members.
We need to set the `DM_PELSHEIGHT`, `DM_PELSWIDTH` and `DM_DISPLAYFIXEDOUTPUT` flags, since we're changing the height, width, and "fixed output" status.

```
DM_PELSHEIGHT := 0x00100000
DM_PELSWIDTH := 0x00080000
DM_DISPLAYFIXEDOUTPUT := 0x20000000

; technically + instead of | (bitwise or) would work the same
flags := DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_DISPLAYFIXEDOUTPUT
```

Then we can `NumPut`. We know `dmFields` to be at offset 40.

```
NumPut(flags, _DEVMODE, 40)
```

Then we can `NumPut` our desired resolution to `dmPelsWidth` (offset 108) and `dmPelsHeight` (offset 112):

```
NumPut(1920, _DEVMODE, 108)
NumPut(1080, _DEVMODE, 112)
```

And then `NumPut` to set the `DMDFO_CENTER` flag to `dmDisplayFixedOutput` (offset 56):

```
NumPut(DMDFO_CENTER := 2, _DEVMODE, 56)
```

Now our structure should be filled with what we want.

> **Note: If you're changing back to the native resolution of your monitor, don't try to use `DMDFO_CENTER` or `DMDFO_STRETCH` flags. Use `DMDFO_DEFAULT`, or don't use the `dmDisplayFixedOutput` member at all.**

---

Now all that's left, is just using the `ChangeDisplaySettingsA`<sup>[(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsa)</sup> function to set our changes:

```
DllCall("ChangeDisplaySettingsA", UInt, &_DEVMODE, UInt, 0)
```

Again, passing in the pointer of our structure and then UInt 0 flag to indicate changing the display settings immediately.

---

> Full example script

```
#NoEnv

ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS := -1

DM_PELSHEIGHT := 0x00100000
DM_PELSWIDTH := 0x00080000
DM_DISPLAYFIXEDOUTPUT := 0x20000000

DMDFO_DEFAULT := 0
DMDFO_STRETCH := 1
DMDFO_CENTER := 2

VarSetCapacity(_DEVMODE, 156)
NumPut(156, _DEVMODE, 36)           ;dmSize

DllCall("EnumDisplaySettingsA", Ptr, 0, UInt, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, UInt, &_DEVMODE)
MsgBox, % NumGet(_DEVMODE, 120) " Hz"

; technically + instead of | (bitwise or) would work the same
flags := DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_DISPLAYFIXEDOUTPUT
NumPut(flags, _DEVMODE, 40)         ;dmFields

NumPut(1920, _DEVMODE, 108)         ;dmPelsWidth
NumPut(1080, _DEVMODE, 112)         ;dmPelsHeight

NumPut(DMDFO_CENTER, _DEVMODE, 56)  ;dmDisplayFixedOutput

DllCall("ChangeDisplaySettingsA", UInt, &_DEVMODE, UInt, 0)
```

---

> Full example script as a function

```
#NoEnv

DMDFO_DEFAULT := 0
DMDFO_STRETCH := 1
DMDFO_CENTER := 2

F1::ChangeDisplaySettings(1920, 1080, DMDFO_CENTER)
F2::ChangeDisplaySettings(3840, 1600, DMDFO_DEFAULT)

ChangeDisplaySettings(width, height, DMDFO)
{
    static ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS := -1
        , DM_PELSHEIGHT := 0x00100000
        , DM_PELSWIDTH := 0x00080000
        , DM_DISPLAYFIXEDOUTPUT := 0x20000000
    
    VarSetCapacity(_DEVMODE, 156)
    NumPut(156, _DEVMODE, 36)       ;dmSize
    
    DllCall("EnumDisplaySettingsA", Ptr, 0, UInt, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, UInt, &_DEVMODE)
    
    ; technically + instead of | (bitwise or) would work the same
    flags := DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_DISPLAYFIXEDOUTPUT
    NumPut(flags, _DEVMODE, 40)     ;dmFields

    NumPut(width, _DEVMODE, 108)    ;dmPelsWidth
    NumPut(height, _DEVMODE, 112)   ;dmPelsHeight

    NumPut(DMDFO, _DEVMODE, 56)     ;dmDisplayFixedOutput

    return DllCall("ChangeDisplaySettingsA", UInt, &_DEVMODE, UInt, 0)
}
```

---

Quite long and possibly overly detailed post for something you might not end up using, but meh, I'm avoiding school work.
It was fun to write and maybe at least someone can learn something from it.

Comment: Wow, so detailed! I didn't just copy\paste your script but read the entire thing. I won't need the "fancy" solution for lpszDeviceName because I only have 1 monitor but it's good to know. Anyway, the Hz msgbox shows the correct 60Hz my monitor is set to. For the initial test, I disregard your note about not using certain members for going back to native and just ran it. Results: When in 1920, script will change it back to native! But when in native, script does nothing (does not change to 1920.) 1: How did back to native work while disregarding your note? 2: Need to get 1920 to work.

Comment: In the bottom most example the hotkeys should be set for F1 to go to 1920x1080 (non stretched) and F2 to go back to native (3840x1600). Worked just fine for me, although I used a different resolution on F2, because native isn't 3840x1600 for me (it's 2560x1440). If you just straight copy paste the bottom most example, does it not work for you?

Comment: I did use the function one. However, I didn't use two hotkeys, I use an if-else, as I posted in my original question. So I declare a variable "x := A_ScreenWidth" and "if (x = 1920)" then "ChangeDisplaySettings(3840, 1600, DMDFO_DEFAULT)" else "ChangeDisplaySettings(1920, 1080, DMDFO_CENTER)". I don't think it would make a difference by using multiple hotkeys.

Comment: Depends on when/how the value of `x` gets updated. But I just meant that exactly copy pasting the F1 F2 version would tell if the problem was on your end, or if there's something wrong with the implementation.

Comment: The "x" gets updated when I click on a key on my GENOVATION MACRO KEYPAD CP48 which runs the AHK file that contains the code. I copied your code exactly except for the two lines with F1 and F2, which I replaced with my if-else. But just for organizational sake, I will try to copy exactly with F1 F2 and will update soon.

Comment: UPDATE: Same thing with F1/F2 copied your script. While in 1920, it will convert back to native fine. But while in native, it does nothing.

Comment: That's odd, not sure what to say about that. I guess should look at the [error values](https://i.imgur.com/rJfJ16q.png) the [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changedisplaysettingsa#return-value) should return. I don't have time to help with that right now though. But I'd say at least experiment around with a different DMDFO mode and different resolutions. Maybe your monitor doesn't like 1920x1080 in `DMDFO_CENTER` for whatever reason.

Comment: Spent hours on this. When using DMDFO_CENTER, the ChangeDisplaySettingsA returns -2 (DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE). There are other posts on StackExchange about DMDFO_CENTER and I tried different ways but nothing helped. I always get 1920 stretched; can't keep the aspect ratio 1:1. I even tried 3rd-party software like "Display Changer II | 12noon" but same issue. By the way, when changing to 1920 via the Nvidia control panel, I also can't get CENTERED. It seems that only changing it manually in Windows display settings utilizes the CENTER somehow. I'm lost.

Comment: At this point, I don't mind the workaround of just getting a simple recording of keystrokes to simulate a manually display change via the Windows display settings but I need a solution as to why the AHK macro recorder will not record down arrows (and when manually coded, not execute) once it gets to the Resolution Dropdown. Even the script (Send, {Enter}) will not execute on the Resolution Dropbox.

Comment: Very weird indeed. I almost wish I had this problem so I could try to solve it myself haha. At this point I would assume the filling of `_DEVMODE` with the current settings fills in some settings that are somehow incompatible with lower resolutions. So I'd try to figure out what in `_DEVMODE` needs to be changed and how. And for your key sending trouble, try running as admin. That might help with the sending of keys.

Comment: Fixed keyboard recording. Stupid me, one row had "[" instead of "{".

Comment: Have an issue. The "ChangeDisplaySettings" function does not change the Administrator account back to native; only my current user account. This causes my computer to always reboot into the 1920x1080 resolution until I login to the Admin account and manually change it back to native there as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Never used Windows with multiple users myself, but seems to me looking into the `dwFlags` parameter in `ChangeDisplaySettings` could be of help. More specifically the `CDS_GLOBAL` or `CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY` flag. Values for the flags are here: https://i.imgur.com/vRTGT7j.png

Comment: I only have one user - me. I was talking about the built-in Administrator account of Windows. We can enable or disable it but it's still built into the system. When you manually change your display, the Admin account's display changes too under the hood - that's normal. But when you manually change it, the Admin change is synced to what you changed it to. With my code, it's not syncing when my code goes to native. I don't use the Admin account, just logged in to check my issue. I'll look into the flags.